# neo4j: Using graph algorithm in cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, dijkstra

How can I use graph algorithm like dijkstra in a cypher query?
There is a rest api for it in Neo4j [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-graph-algos).

Also I know that I can get the result with following query:

```
START  startNode=node:node_auto_index(name={startNode}),
   endNode=node:node_auto_index(name={endNode})
MATCH  p=(startNode)-[:CONNECTED_TO*1..4]->(endNode)
RETURN p AS shortestPath, 
       reduce(weight=0, r in relationships(p) : weight+r.weight) AS totalWeight
       ORDER BY totalWeight ASC
       LIMIT 1
```

But this isn't really run dijkstra algorithm and It's very heavier.(for a highly connected 1m node graph)

I want to find the shortest weighted path. 
I'm using neo4j jdbc driver and standalone server(not embedded mode).

Comment: Look at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#graph-algorithms-work-in-progress